# How to inject a .Net DLL into an unmanaged process?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

After our senior developer left last week, I've been assigned to a task in which I need to inject a dll written in C# and invoke a method into another process which is not made using .Net, it's written in C++.
I'm not a C/C++ guy and honestly I do not understand half of what I read till now.
Searching for "How to inject a .Net DLL into an unmanaged processes?" and queries like this only brings one practical [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-Net-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes) on code project which I have difficulty to follow due to so many errors.
How can I do this without thinking about suicide?

Comment: It's _probably_ written in C++... It matters!

Comment: I was going to update my question, Yes, It's written in VC++ .

Comment: You should do this step by step. You need to create a new instance of CLR which will be a host for your .NET application/library. Then you need to "run/inject" desired managed application/library. It most likely will be error prone as hell.

Comment: I see nothing but errors actually. Could you please provide a more practical guide with code samples, like a link, an article, sample codes or anything that I can read through to understand.

Comment: @JeremyMc If you would post some code then we could review this and propose some changes, without that i can only speculate what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @m.rogalski Before posting the question I asked for permission to post a part of the code, but I was strictly prohibited from doing so as it is 'Company's Intellectual Property'. :(

Comment: @JeremyMc That's pretty common behavior in companies. I'll try to make some code sample when i get back from work. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Your scenario is unclear, mainly because your terms are unclear. A DLL is a library, an *assembly* is a file with managed code (which could be an EXE or a DLL). You can't have an "unmanaged assembly". Is your question simply on how to load a managed assembly into an unmanaged process, or is a unmanaged DLL involved somewhere? By "inject", do you literally mean you want to have the assembly loaded without the process taking action (the usual meaning of "injecting") or do you mean the process is going to actively load your library? How is the "method" you want to invoke declared?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your corrections. You were completely right.
I edited the question, by "inject",as you have already pointed out, I mean loading the dll inside a running process without the process taking action.
The method I need to inject is a simple static method returning a boolean value, and inside the body it writes some data to a database.

Comment: In that case, the article you linked to describes what you want pretty well. It may contain minor errors (I haven't followed everything step-by-step), but the technique is sound. This is not an easy thing to do if you don't know anything about unmanaged code, though. As a question it's simply too broad for SO. You'll have to bite the bullet, work through it and search for/ask individual questions if you fail at any point. Or, alternatively, consider other solutions; injecting code is always a dubious pastime.